# Why use dynamic_sidebar() conditionally?

Tags: widgets, sidebar

In the [codex example of displaying sidebars](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API#Displaying_Widgets_and_Widget_Areas), what is the significance of the conditional wrapping around the call to dynamic_sidebar? Why do this:

```
<?php if ( dynamic_sidebar('example_widget_area_name') ) : else : endif; ?>
```

this seems to work ok:

```
<?php dynamic_sidebar('example_widget_area_name'); ?>
```

Thanks,

Toby

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar)

> The return value should be used to determine whether to display a static sidebar. This ensures that your theme will look good even when the Widgets plug-in is not active.

So essentially you can use is to display other content if the user has not activated any widgets in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that helps. So if my theme should only display the sidebar (or nothing) it's ok to skip the conditional stuff?

Comment: Yes that's absolutely fine, it's just been the convention to include a conditional statement in case you want other content should the user not have any widgets active

Comment: It's a holdover from the time when the widgets system was a plugin and not built into WordPress. It is not strictly necessary any longer.